Excel: How to extract a certain word, from a list of words, from a range of cells?
I'm looking to extract the varietal type of a wine, from a list of wine names. There's no formatting consistency. I've got a list of 8 potential wine types (shiraz, rosé, chardonnay, etc.) and about 1000 rows of wine names. I'm looking for a search function that can scan a cell for the varietal (from the above list), then in a seperate cell return the matching type.

Tried a few =LEFT and =RIGHT functions with character counts but cant get it going.

try this:
=INDEX(MyVarietals,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MyVarietals,C2)),0))

To simplify the formula, I assigned the range name "MyVarietals" to the range F2:F8.

If the Varietals contain names that are a partial match, like Cabernet is a partial match for Cabernet Sauvignon, or Blanc is a partial match for Sauvignon Blanc, make sure to order the list of varietals to have the more complex names at the top. This way, the more complex name will be first in the array of True/False returned by the Isnumber function and will be picked by the Match function.

It was my solution as well and it works based on the supplied examples.  It will not work correctly if the look up list contains such varieties as for example "Cabernet" and "Cabernet Sauvignon" and a wine name will be "bla bla Cabernet Sauvignon bla".  The formula will return "Cabernet" only.

@Michal - it works fine for all kinds of names. I edited my answer to explain how to ensure partial matches are returning the correct varietal.

not sure if expecting the end user to maintain the potential look up list in a strict order is a good idea (certainly a courageous one).


If you have Excel 365.  It does not require any special sorting of the Variety table.  I'm sure it can be simplified as it's rather convoluted right now:
=LET(
var,IFERROR(MID(A5,SEARCH(MyVarietals,A5),LEN(MyVarietals)),""),
complex_name,IFERROR(IF(FIND(" ",var)>0,var,""),""),
filter_complex,FILTER(complex_name,complex_name<>""),
filter_name,FILTER(var,var<>""),
count,COUNTA(filter_name),
IF(count=1,filter_name,filter_complex))

